# Происхождение слова ругань

Tags: этимология

Лексемы брань и ругань - синонимы ныне,  хотя ранее "бранью" называли битву, сражение, бой. Интересно узнать о происхождении слова "ругань".

Answer (score 3):

**Этимологический словарь Макса Фасмера**

**Ругать**

Происходит от **праслав. формы**, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. **ругъ** «насмешка»...родственно  лат. **ringor** «разеваю рот, скалю зубы, сержусь».

Однако **Черных** считает, что значение "бранить" в славянских языках не первичное, старшее значение – это **изгибаться, кривиться, дергаться.**

Это значение он выводит из и.-е. базы **uer-g** – вертеть, поворачивать, сгибать.

Тот же корень он выделяет в о.-с. основе **verg** (русский вариант: отвергать, низвергать).

Поэтому  происхождение слова ***ругать***  **не совсем ясное.**

**Как образовалось существительное ругань:**

Ругать – ругань, рвать – рвань, ткать – ткань, дать – дань, бранить – брань.

Суффикс Н(Ь) используется для образования существительных, обозначающих собирательные понятия, являющиеся объектом или результатом действия (из словаря Ефремовой).